# Unable to install python packages in PyCharm usind conda

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

[image]

I am trying use install package feature of PyCharm. I have conda python as my python interpreter.

PyCharm is trying to use conda to install the package using
`Conda /home/jkl/anaconda3/bin/conda install -p / BeautifulSoup -y`
but it's not successful

I cannot find where this above command is configured in pycharm. where is this command configured in pychram?

How do I use PIP instead of conda to install packages in pycharm with conda python interpreter?

Comment: Just go to (project) settings, click interpreter then create a new interpreter, Pycharm will be guiding you towards creating a new virtual environment, And you can add your packages under that new virtual environment that you created. Plus, if you list all the packages inside `requirements.txt`, Pycharm will automatically detect and prompt you to install.

Comment: creating a new environment seems to solve the issue, but how do I solve it without creating a new environment? I want to know why are installation in my current conda default env are  not going through? what is indicating PyCharm to use conda instead of pip?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it's

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

and not

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: It happens with all packages, not just bs4